# First error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Assigned To ID: owner cannot be blank: [OwnerId]

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, soql

I am writing a test for my controller. For that I have to insert an event in the test database.

My test method is:

```
static TestMethod void Test1_TestInsertWithValue()
{
    Meeting_Master__c master = new Meeting_Master__c();
    Event event = new Event();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id From Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
    User u2 = new User(Alias = 'newUser', Email = 'newuser@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', LastName = 'Testing',
    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', LocaleSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='newuser@testorg.com', ProfileId=p.Id);

    event.OwnerId = u2.Id;
    event.StartDateTime = datetime.newInstance(2008, 12, 1);
    event.EndDateTime = datetime.newInstance(2008, 12, 30);
    event.subject = 'call';
    event.WhatId = master.Id;
    insert master;
    insert event;
    ...........
}
```

When the insert event occurs, I am facing this error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Assigned To ID: owner cannot be blank: [OwnerId]

How do I rectify this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first option you can insert test user:

```
 @isTest
 private class test{

     static TestMethod void Test1_TestInsertWithValue() {
         Meeting_Master__c master=new Meeting_Master__c();
         Event event =new Event();
         Profile p=[SELECT Id From Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
         User u2 =new User( Alias = 'newUser1' ,
                            Email ='newuser123@testorg.com',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                            LastName = 'Testing',
                            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                            LocaleSidKey='en_US', // changed for to avoid: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Locale: bad value for restricted picklist field: America/Los_Angeles
                            UserName='newuser123@testorg.com',
                            ProfileId=p.Id,
                            TimeZoneSidKey    = 'America/Los_Angeles');
         insert u2;

         event.OwnerId = u2.Id;
         event.StartDateTime = datetime.newInstance(2008, 12, 1);
         event.EndDateTime = datetime.newInstance(2008,12,10); // changed to 10-12-2008 for to avoid: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Event duration can not be longer than 14 days
         event.subject='call';
         event.WhatId=master.Id;
         Insert master;
         insert event;
     }

 }
```

The second option is a trying to use `System.runAs()` 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

```
 @isTest
 private class test{

     static TestMethod void Test1_TestInsertWithValue() {
         Meeting_Master__c master=new Meeting_Master__c();
         Event event =new Event();
         Profile p=[SELECT Id From Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
         User u2 =new User( Alias = 'newUser1' ,
                            Email ='newuser123@testorg.com',
                            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                            LastName = 'Testing',
                            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                            LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
                            UserName='newuser123@testorg.com',
                            ProfileId=p.Id,
                            TimeZoneSidKey    = 'America/Los_Angeles');

         Insert master;

         System.runAs(u2) {
            event.StartDateTime = datetime.newInstance(2008, 12, 1);
            event.EndDateTime = datetime.newInstance(2008,12,10);
            event.subject='call';
            event.WhatId=master.Id;

            insert event;
         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: please reply to this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912599/parsing-json-object-in-salesforce-apex

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to insert `u2` before the line `event.OwnerId =u2.Id;`.